# TFLite model converter does not output uint8

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow-lite

I have trained a custom Keras network and I wanted to deploy it on an MCU. I have to quantize it to UINT8.

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('saved_model/MaskNet_extended.h5')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE]
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.inference_input_type = [tf.uint8]
converter.inference_output_type = [tf.uint8]
converter.representative_dataset = rep_ds
tflite_quant_model = converter.convert()
```

The problem is that tf_lite_quant_model is stil Float32.
How is this possible?

The network is:

```
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', 
           input_shape=(IMG_SHAPE)),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')
])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in TFLiteConverterV2, there's a workaround to solve it in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/tools/optimize/python/modify_model_interface.py.

TensorFlow Lite will also output uint8 very soon.